# Howto distribute crystal-lang executable

Tags: crystal-lang

Hello Crystal priests,

I have built an app, snob, on my development vm running crystal 0.23.1 on fedora26. It runs fine locally. This is a release build. I copy the app to my host machine, fedora27, and attempt to run it, I get an error complaining about shard.yml. The same happens on any of my centos machines. The error:

```
Error opening file 
'/vagrant/Projects/crystal/snob/src/snob/../../shard.yml' with mode 'r': No such file or directory (Errno)
Failed to raise an exception: END_OF_STACK
[0x40e807] __crystal_raise +375
[0x411f05] ???
[0x41f595] ???
[0x417291] ???
[0x41611a] ???
[0x42d37a] main +7914
[0x7f8783b5100a] __libc_start_main +234
[0x40e2da] _start +42
[0x0] ???
```

What am I missing? I was under the impression that this is a stand-alone executable. No amount of head scratching or googling is turning up anything.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me. Meanwhile, I'm still looking.

Comment: That's not a question I can answer without sourcecode. It seems someone has written code inside your application or one of the shards it uses which depends on `shard.yml`. Crystal executables are normally standalone but it's possible to write one which is not, that's what has happened here.

Comment: I looked closer at my source and found that including a reference to shard.yml in version.cr caused the problem. Instead of: `VERSION = "x.x.x"` I had tried to use `VERSION = begin
    YAML.parse(File.read(File.join(__DIR__, "../..",
      "shard.yml")))["version"].as_s
  end
` Thank you @RX14 for your response.

Comment: How about answering your own question with the solution you found? Then the question can get closed. And your problem could be frequent for some time, so a nice solution could interest enthusiasts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Crystal v0.24.1 and Shards v0.7.2 I can now keep versions in one place using:

     `` VERSION = {{ `shards version #{__DIR__}`.chomp.stringify }} ``

This fixes the problem I created above.

Answer (score 1):

My source code in version.cr:

`VERSION = begin
  YAML.parse(File.join(__DIR__, "../..", "shard.yml")))["version"].as_s
end`

I was trying to keep the version in one place for updating during developing and inadvertently introduced an unwanted error. My app now depended on having shard.yml located in my path somewhere. Ouch! Changing the VERSION constant to a literal string, "x.x.x" and rebuilding fixed the issue. My source is located at https://github.com/lebogan/snob.git.

Thanks @Eric Platon for the posting suggestion.